# Can't create handler... on dialog creation

Tags: android, dialog, runtimeexception

I am getting the error

```
02-11 21:40:25.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

when trying to create a dialog. The class that I need to do this in does not extend activity (I pass context to this class from another class), so I am looking for a way to create a simple popup message in the default android style without this error. Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: See my answer please, it just describes why you get that RuntimeException. Show your code to make your question clear

Answer (score 0):

By default only main thread(UI thread) has a `looper` which you can use to process your events. That means when you create a child thread(non-UI thread) , it will not have a `looper`. By calling `Looper.prepare`, you create a new `Looper` object for your child thread and only then you can get a `handler` object. But I guess this is not you want (The `Looper` is used inside `Handler` and normally you don't care about its usage. ).

An approach is using [`getMainLooper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper%28%29) as the parameter to handler constructor . This way you use the same looper object as that of the UI thread